# Keywords settings for the appStore

Tags: app-store, keyword

Here is a question about the setting of keywords for an app on the appStore.
Let me take an example. Let us say my app is called Shakespeare and it is an English learning app.
The first two keywords coming to my mind are: English and Learning.
Obviously only with those two keywords, there are already a number of ways a user might perform a search.
Giving only a few examples here:

1. Search for: “English Learning”.
2. Search for: “Learning English”.
3. Search for: “english learning”.
4. Search for: “english”.
5. Search for: “english study”.

And I could easily make the list much longer.

My question is (only sticking with my two keywords) what is the best way to put them when filling the form for the submission to the appStore?

1. “English,Learning”
2. “English,Learning, English Learning, Learning English”
3. ??

If 1) is OK to match all cases obviously that is better. Do the cases matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 matches all cases.I tested that right now.